# What was the conversation between Ravana and Lakshmana when Ravana was on death bed

Tags: ramayana, rama, ravana, lakshmana

Please provide verse too and sources.
What are the conversations between them and where it is mentioned with verse numbers.
There are no shastric evidence in other questions